# How to reference active delayed_job within the actual job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am working on a solution to display the percentage completion of a delayed job (using the delayed_job gem). At the present, I have a database migration that looks like the following for my delayed_jobs table:

```
class CreateDelayedJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :delayed_jobs, :force => true do |table|
      table.integer  :priority, :default => 0      # Allows some jobs to jump to the front of the queue
      table.integer  :attempts, :default => 0      # Provides for retries, but still fail eventually.
      table.text     :handler                      # YAML-encoded string of the object that will do work
      table.text     :last_error                   # reason for last failure (See Note below)
      table.datetime :run_at                       # When to run. Could be Time.zone.now for immediately, or sometime in the future.
      table.datetime :locked_at                    # Set when a client is working on this object
      table.datetime :failed_at                    # Set when all retries have failed (actually, by default, the record is deleted instead)
      table.string   :locked_by                    # Who is working on this object (if locked)
      table.string   :queue                        # The name of the queue this job is in
      table.integer  :progress
      table.timestamps

    end

    add_index :delayed_jobs, [:priority, :run_at], :name => 'delayed_jobs_priority'
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :delayed_jobs
  end
end
```

I am using an enqueue process within a controller method for a delayed job, and referencing a class in lib/build_detail.rb :

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(BuildDetail.new(@object, @com))
```

The lib/build_detail.rb file is as follows:

```
class BuildDetail < Struct.new(:object, :com)

  def perform
    total_count = object.person_ids.length
    progress_count = 0

    people = com.person object.person_ids do |abc|
      progress_count += abc.size
      Delayed::Job.current.update_attribute :progress, (progress_count/total_count)
    end
  end  

end
```

Delayed::Job.current doesn't work. I see the Delayed::Job.current method proposed on [this posting](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sdruby/0OIj0XKsnrg), however it looks like the method was never included in the main delayed_jobs github project.

How can I access the current job (from within the actual job), to update the progress field each time my job goes through the loop?

Answer (score 10):

It's to late to answer but I've faced with the same requirement so may be it will help someone.
All you need to do is to implement custom job and `before`-hook where you will store reference on current job:

```
class MyTestJob
  def before(job)
    @job = job
  end

  def perform
    ...
    @job.update_attributes({ progress: your_progress_var }, without_protection: true)
  end
end
```

Comment: A more detailed explanation than "All you need to do" would be helpful.

Comment: @IanLewis as it says you just have to create your custom job and override `before` method to save your current job. that's all

Comment: Thank you @aray I was reading "custom job" as being something different to a 'job'.

Answer (score 0):

One of the cool things about delayed job is also what is thwarting you here.  When you queue up lots of delayed jobs, you can work them off in parallel if you have multiple instances running workers - e.g. you could have 10 machines each running an instance of your app accessing the same database and get 10x speed boost of the processing.  Because of that, there could be multiple "current" jobs.  Having only one job running at a time is a bit of a special case.

Here's a way to see the status of all active jobs.  If you only have one instance running, it will only return one job, so that will satisfy your situation:

```
active_jobs = Delayed::Job.where("progress > 0")
progress_of_first_job = active_jobs.first.progress if active_jobs.present?
progress_of_all_jobs = active_jobs.map{|job| job.progress}
```

progress_of_first_job is the progress of one of the jobs (use an order clause to be safe).
progress_of_all_jobs is a (possibly empty) array of progress values for each active job.

Comment: I appreciate your comments about the benefit of multiple instances of background workers. The progress field is one I added myself, not one supported natively by the the Delayed_Job gem. My challenge is precisely as you identified - being able to update the progress of a specific job, from within the code that specifies the payload of the job itself. As far as I can tell, the native Delayed_Job gem doesn't have this functionality. I know that the gem has some callback hooks, but nothing that would facilitate the creation of a progress bar.

Comment: If only I could reference the active job within the payload creation process of the delayed job. I have been reading about Resque, and it looks like I may have to go that route if I can't get delayed jobs to update the progress.

Comment: Actually, I took a look at the ``Delayed::Job::Lifecycle`` class, and it looks like it passes in the *worker* and *job* to the *process* method.  If you rewrite the signature of your perform method to ``def perform worker, job``, you should be able to access the job object and write out the progress there.  e.g ``job.update_attribute :progress, 0.5``

Comment: Hmmm... I have tried this, and it doesn't look like it's possible to reference the job within the perform method. Some of the callbacks accept `job` as an argument. Strange - I would think that this is a fairly common request for `delayed_job` users.

Comment: If you can't get at the job itself, you could add a ``progress`` column to your class or add a wrapper class that has a ``progress`` that you set in the perform method.  You could then use ``BuildDetail.where("progress > 0")`` to find active jobs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're also using ActiveJob, in an initializer, you can monkey patch the JobWrapper class.

```
module ActiveJob
  module QueueAdapters
    class DelayedJobAdapter
      class JobWrapper
        def perform(job)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```