# Record progress for long running ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, rails-activejob

Based on this question [How to reference active delayed_job within the actual job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613122/how-to-reference-active-delayed-job-within-the-actual-job) I'm using Delayed::Job with an additional `progress` text column to record progress of a long running task.

I'm now trying to update my code to use ActiveJob, so I've replaced `def before` with `before_perform`, but the `job` object passed to `before_perform` is not the same as the one passed to `before`. And quite rightly, because the queue adapter is configurable and may not always be :delayed_job.

So, given that the queue adapter is configurable, is there a correct way to access (read *and* write) the `progress` column in table `delayed_jobs`?

Thanks.